# how to make gridview shows both scrolls when the height is set to auto

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, gridview

Please I have a gridview whose div is set to height:auto and the overflow:auto.
I want a situation whereby the div where the gridview is placed will show its vertical scrollbars and scrollable when a certail height is reached.

Or to make the grid scrollable vertically always irrespective of the height.

This is the code snippet

```
<div id="tablePlaceholder" style="float: left; width: 54%; height: 100%; overflow: auto" onscroll="Onscrollfnction();">
    <%--style="float: left; width: 59%;overflow: auto;--%>
    <asp:GridView ID="ProductsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="ProductsGridView_RowDataBound" CssClass="fht-table">
        <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="ProductRow" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="ProductRow" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingProductRow" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the gridview with container `<div>` and apply the CSS to it:

```
<style type="text/css">
#tablePlaceholder {
   height:auto;
   overflow:scroll;
   max-height:450px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding this in the CSS
Instead of overflow auto?

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
```